# Sqlyog: copy table from localhost to remote server without duplicate records

Tags: mysql

Hi guys i want to copy record from table which is stored in localhost into remote server but when i tried to copy there is pop up like below:

[image]

If i checked `Drop if exists in target` it would delete all of data in table, but if unchecked it would duplicate several record,that's why i want to copy record from table in localhost into remote server without duplicate data or delete existing data, so just adding new data from localhost table and ignoring existing data. Is there any way to use such a feature like that in sqlyog ? if not how could i to do this task ?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your table *first* into a temporary table in your *source* database, copy that table to the *target* database, and merge the data there.

That is, in your *source* database:

```
CREATE TABLE emails_temp AS
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    emails ;
```

... copy this table to the *target* database using the <kbd>Copy Database</kbd> functionality; and drop it from the original:

```
 DROP TABLE emails_temp ;
```

Once you have your temporal table at the destination, add the new data to the existing table, doing something like:

```
INSERT INTO emails
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    emails_temp
WHERE 
    primary_key NOT IN (SELECT primary_key FROM emails) ;
```

(Obviously, you have to substitute `primary_key` by your actual PRIMARY KEY).

Or you can use also `INSERT IGNORE`.

After you have transferred all the new rows, you can

```
DROP TABLE emails_temp ; -- At the destination database
```